# Get User's other field instead of Username,in the View?

Tags: 8, users, views

I have one content type called "Test".In that content type i have Entity Reference field Referencing to Users called "field_authors"[**can have more than one user**] . I have created a view of this type.Here while showing 'field_authors' , it is showing User username, but Instead of username ,i want to show other field value of the User.
How can i achieve this? Can anybody please help me?
Drupal version:8.2.0
**Details:**
Currently View table column Output is: CC111,CC112,CC113 [which are the usernames of different users in the site]
I need user's other fields like "First name" instead of username in above Case.
I tried adding Relationship '(author) field_authors' and Added field in view Table 'field_authors'[selected use relationship] , But still output is CC111,CC112,CC113 etc instead of comma separated names.
I Got partial output after adding Relationship to that field,but since it is a multi field,output is coming in 3 different rows.Instead of it I need output in one row comma separated values.[Ex:Name1,Name2,Name3]

Comment: You've used the tag relationships two times, but not mentioned it in the question, did you actually add a relationship to the view?

Comment: Yeah 4k4 is right you need to provide more details about your view. Maybe you could post a screenshot of that one with the advanced tab expanded. Then we will be able to help you much more easily :)

Comment: I have added some more details,in my question.Please check

Answer (score 1):

In order to use fields of user, you have to add a relationship  (panel to the right, under contextual filter). Create a relation to the user entity.

Comment: I tried adding Relationship , but was not working.